# Need to delete mails for a range of dates in Linux

Tags: email, mail-command

I have 1 million mails generated in a Linux server due to a cron job. I want to delete the mails, but not all as this cron mails useful to troubleshoot and find out the issue with cron job's execution. So I need to keep one month's mail and remove the remaining.

Comment: How is your mail kept on your system? In a single file, in a mail directory, in a database? How do you access it? Directly in the filesystem, through IMAP?

Comment: I am accessing though mail command. I need to delete the mails whichever more than 1 month old.

Answer (score 7):

There are many different `mail` commands out there with different command sets. POSIX standardizes a [`mailx`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mailx.html) command.

Your mailbox will typically contain emails in the order in which they were received. So to delete older mails, you would typically delete lower-numbered emails. You can delete a range of messages with a command like `d 1-42` (delete the first 42 messages).

If you want more control, I recommend [Mutt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_(email_client)), a command line email client that gives you a lot more control than the `mail` command. Mutt has a text mode interface and can also be scripted. In Mutt, you can use the [command](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-2.html#ss2.3) `D` to mark messages for deletion and enter the [pattern](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#ss4.2) `~d ->1m` to select messages that are more than 1 month old. If you're satisfied with the list of messages to delete, type `x` to delete the messages marked for deletion.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gilles. Yes its working. But Can I have the exact script to delete the mails which are more than one month old with this mutt command.

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of searching I found [archivemail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/archivemail.1.html) using which was able to clear old mails.

The syntax is:

```
archivemail -d 30 --delete <path-to-mailbox>
```

(In usual cases `$MAIL` defines the local mailbox location, try `echo $MAIL` to check).

You can also check what it is going to do with the `-n` (*--dry-run*) option.

Comment: One annoyance with `archivemail`, at least on CentOS, is that it refuses to process mail files under `/var/spool/mail` (ie: the above example with `$MAIL` doesn't work on CentOS).  This is because it insists on being able to write in the directory alongside the mail file (which strictly speaking, it shouldn't need to)... A workaround is to copy the mail file to a temp location for processing and copy it back afterwards; which raises an issue with concurrent modification of the underlying file.

Comment: @sxc731 I was able to reproduce the issue (got: archivemail: no write permission on output directory: '/var/mailtest'). Could try filing a bug report. Btw would it be reasonable for you to change permissions for `/var/spool/mail`? On ubuntu it seems to be *drwxrwsrwt*.

Comment: Hi there, actually on my Ubuntu Xenial (and later) boxes `/var/spool/mail` is `drwxrwsr-x` (not sure how you ended up with smth different?).  Come to think of it, it's probably fair enough for it not to be world-writable.  As for the bug report; it would probably have to be filed against the Python `mailbox` module...

Comment: I dunno, on the system I checked somehow the permissions got modified; on another system I too have `drwxrwsr-x`. I checked the code, and found the error there: https://sourceforge.net/p/archivemail/code/ci/master/tree/archivemail (near the end, in function *check_sane_destdir*).

Comment: under a legacy `rpm` based Linux I was able to create an `rpm` for `archivemail` using https://docs.python.org/2.0/dist/creating-rpms.html - it works perfectly for archiving `sent` mail from `mutt` - you need to `su` to the user who owns the `sent` file

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling with this same issue for a while, and Googling for a simple answer was tougher than expected for the mail server I'm administering.

I needed to delete mail from a single user's mailbox which was regularly filling up the filesystem and ended up with the following cron job:

```
18 5 * * * /usr/bin/mutt -f /var/spool/mail/developer -e "push D~d>7d<enter>qy<enter>"
```

Or: at 05:18 every day, run mutt on file (directory in this case) /var/spool/mail/developer, wait until mutt is up (push), mark for deletion (D) patterns matching (~) date (d) older than 7 days (>7d),  to conclude that command, then quit (q) and confirm deletion (y)

Answer (score 0):

`mutt` can delete using regular expressions, details [here](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#regexp) and [here](http://jim-zimmerman.com/?p=922).

Comment: Hi Jan, 
Yes its working. But Can I have the exact script to delete the mails which are more than one month old with this mutt command.

Comment: To select messages olther than one month, use `~d >1m`

Comment: First link (http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#ss4.2) is dead. I get a 404.

Comment: @Bulrush Thank you, updated the link to point to the new location.